# i was getting the error: undeclared variable: IO in the following java program, but the code is right according to my knowledge

Tags: java, bluej

```java
  public class CourseGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int examWeight = 70;
        int labWeight = 20;
        int hwWeight = 10;
        double examScore;
        double labScore;
        double hwScore;
        double finalScore;

        //ask Student to input scores for exam, lab, hw
        IO.output("Enter your exam scores: ");
        examScore = IO.inputDouble();
        IO.output("Enter your lab scores: ");
        labScore = IO.inputDouble();
        IO.output("Enter your homework scores: ");
        hwScore = IO.inputDouble();

        //compute final score as the weighted sum of exam, lab, hw score
        examScore = examScore * (examWeight / 100);
        labScore = labScore * (labWeight / 100);
        hwScore = hwScore * (hwWeight / 100);

        finalScore = examScore + labScore + hwScore;

        // output the final score
        IO.outputln("Your final score is: " + finalScore);
    }
}
```

I was getting this error:
`undeclared variable:IO` again and again, and this solution problem is not available on the web

I am running this code in bluej editor for java
in my opinion `io` part is just related to the syntax

Comment: You have not declared anything called IO.  Possibly it's supposed to be imported, but there are no import statements.  Where do you suppose 'IO' is defined?  It is not part of the Java language.  Is it supposed to be provided by the coursework envrironment?

Answer (score 1):

You would need the **IO** class which contains several methods to run your code. The **IO** class might look something like this:

```
public class IO {
    
    private static java.util.Scanner userIN = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void output(Object input) {
        System.out.print(input);
    }

    public static void outputln(Object input) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    
    public static void outputf(String input, Object[] varArgs) {
        System.out.printf(input, varArgs);
    }
    
    public static String inputLine() {
        return userIN.nextLine();
    }
    
    public static String inputToken() {
        return userIN.next();
    }
    
    public static int inputInt() {
        int i = userIN.nextInt();
        userIN.nextLine(); // Consume ENTER key.
        return i;
    }
    
    public static long inputLong() {
        long i = userIN.nextLong();
        userIN.nextLine(); // Consume ENTER key.
        return i;
    }
    
    public static double inputDouble() {
        double i = userIN.nextDouble();
        userIN.nextLine(); // Consume ENTER key.
        return i;
    }
    
    public static float inputFloat() {
        float i = userIN.nextFloat();
        userIN.nextLine(); // Consume ENTER key.
        return i;
    }
    
    public static void inputClose() {
        userIN.close();
    }

    // Add more methods as required....
}
```

Too use with **your** code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                          
    int examWeight = 70;
    int labWeight = 20;
    int hwWeight = 10;
    double examScore;
    double labScore;
    double hwScore;
    double finalScore;

    //ask Student to input scores for exam, lab, hw
    IO.output("Enter your exam scores: ");
    examScore = IO.inputDouble();
    IO.output("Enter your lab scores: ");
    labScore = IO.inputDouble();
    IO.output("Enter your homework scores: ");
    hwScore = IO.inputDouble();

    //compute final score as the weighted sum of exam, lab, hw score
    examScore = examScore * (examWeight / 100d);
    labScore = labScore * (labWeight / 100d);
    hwScore = hwScore * (hwWeight / 100d);

    finalScore = examScore + labScore + hwScore;

    // output the final score
    IO.outputln("Your final score is: " + finalScore);
}
```